# How to solve 'Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.3'

Tags: javascript, android-studio, react-native, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I created a react-native project now when i want to start it by command '`react-native run-android`', i give an error:

> Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.3

this is the full error:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to ensure that you have the Build Tools version.

Open Android Studio and the SDK Manager can be accessed from the "Welcome to Android Studio" screen. Click on "Configure", then select "SDK Manager".

Select the "SDK Tools" tab and check the box next to "Show Package Details". Look for and expand the "Android SDK Build-Tools" entry, then make sure that `26.0.3` is selected.

Take a look here in the Android section and make sure you've set everything up correctly:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks, i went to 'SDK Tools' and i looked for '26.0.3' but it was not there. how can i add it to my SDK tools?

Comment: Does the window look like this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/GettingStartedAndroidSDKManagerSDKToolsWindows.png - just tick the 26.0.3 and hit 'Apply'. If that fails you can build the project in Android Studio and it should give you the option on the error to download the missing build tools

Comment: no, it does not. this is my window: http://s8.picofile.com/file/8336980468/Untitled.png

Comment: What SDK Platforms do you have? (The tab to the left of SDK Tools)